# Sinks.many() with different speed of consumers

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have dilemma, which (how) to use project reactor with real world scenario.

I have need to distribute events to all connected clients (browsers, using http and Server Sent Events). For simplicity, I am testing things as unit tests, with console subscribers.

Sample code for testing https://gist.github.com/luvarqpp/8ea6ad5ad32a8fcbf3264c00ebe351b2

My target is to make able publishing broadcast events and receive them in different browsers in different speeds.

I would like to disconnect client, when it does handle pace of events. So he will need to reconnect, to receive stream again.

PS: Sending/pushing to http can be done using SSE, simple sample code: https://gist.github.com/luvarqpp/dc941ab368504a525ac66716253b04d7

PS2: Bonus would be to be able to make "[smart batching](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/smart-batching.html)" possible to happen. i.e., when some client have X events in buffer on server side, call to custom code would make shrink of given events. Reason about events as updates to key,value database. So any update to same key can be shrunk to single update (latest value).

My approaches was using:

```
Sinks.many().replay().limit(0); // latest();
Sinks.many().multicast().directAllOrNothing();
Sinks.many().multicast().directBestEffort();
Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer(8);
```